# Distribute msvcr90.dll without the rest of Microsoft.VC90.CRT?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, assemblies, software-distribution, msvcr90.dll

I have an EXE which was built from C source code using Visual Studio 2008. The EXE therefore contains a manifest which includes the following:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT" version="9.0.21022.8" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
</dependentAssembly>
```

I would like to distribute this EXE so that it will run on any Windows XP or newer system, whether `Microsoft.VC90.CRT` has been installed or not. Documentation (e.g. [private assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235291(v=vs.90).aspx)) states that this can be done by including the following files alongside the EXE:

```
Microsoft.VC90.CRT\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest
Microsoft.VC90.CRT\msvcr90.dll
Microsoft.VC90.CRT\msvcp90.dll
Microsoft.VC90.CRT\msvcm90.dll
```

Is it necessary to include all 4 of these files? Because my source code is pure C, my EXE is dependent only on `msvcr90.dll`. On first glance it seems I should be able to do without `msvcp90.dll` and `msvcm90.dll`.

Is it OK to distribute only `msvcr90.dll` (and `Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest`)? Are there any downsides to doing so?

Comment: You only have to deploy what you use, it cannot go wrong when your program never actually loads the DLL.  Be careful with the manifest, it has to be considerably hacked from the default one.  If your program consists of *just* the EXE and doesn't use other DLLs then build your program with /MT so you don't need those DLLs at all.  And consider updating your VS version, these manifest headaches are ancient history.

Comment: @HansPassant: "the manifest [...] has to be considerably hacked" - do you mean that I have to change the contents of the `Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest` file? In what way?